# Dual Booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Raid 0 grub installation failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, raid, mdadm

I am fairly new to Ubuntu so bear with me. I recently built a PC and I wanted to run software RAID 0 on my two 1T SSDs; however, I also want to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10. In the installation of Ubuntu, I was able to install mdadm and recognize my RAID setup and partitions, but the install fails with the following:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/md0p1' failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

Trying the command in the terminal I get the error:

```
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I looked into this error online, and there were a lot of different answers from years ago, but it seemed like it might be a problem with how my efi boot partition was mounted. After running the installation and coming across the error, my boot partition is mounted at /target/boot/efi. I tried mounting it to /boot/efi or changing my efi-directory in grub-install, and those give the following output:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: disk 'mduuid/00000000000000000000000000000000,1' not found.
```

From here I am not sure where to go. It seems like the uuid is wrong here, though I am not sure where I would change that for grub-installer.

I also tried turning off fast/quick boot and secure boot as suggested in a few posts to no avail.

The steps I took before this:

1. Created my RAID 0 array using Intel RST in the UEFI before installing Windows 10
2. Installed Windows 10 onto the RAIDed drives and used the Windows partitioning tool to allocate free space for the Ubuntu installation
3. Downloaded the iso image for Ubuntu and created a LiveUSB to boot from
4. Selected "Try Ubuntu" to remove dmraid and install mdadm
5. Ran the following:

   sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1

   so that Ubuntu would recognize the RAID and the partitions created in Windows.
6. Ran the installer and chose "Something else".
7. Mounted the Ubuntu partition, /dev/md0p5, to root with ext4 and set the boot partition to /dev/md0p1 (it had the boot and esp tags, so I assumed it was the Windows bootloader)
8. Received the error described previously after going through the rest of the installer

I hope that was enough information to be of use; this is like my 8th time trying to do this, so I've forgotten a lot of what I've looked up and tried. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 22 with latest linux kernel doesn't seem to have intel fake raid driver anymore. I guess intel is to blame

Answer (score 0):

My filesystem is also in an Intel RAID 0.
Ubuntu let me upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.01, but after reboot Ubuntu doesn't start, and it opens the “initramfs” command line because it cannot find the disk UUID of the RAID 0.

Also, the Ubuntu 22.04.1, launched from the bootable USB stick, doesn't recognize the RAID 0 partition.

Ubuntu 20.04.4, launched from the bootable USB stick, recognizes the RAID 0 partition, and all users' data.

So, be very careful to upgrade if you are using RAID.